# Erro ao executar procedure com output no SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, pl-sql, procedure, sqldeveloper

podem ajudar?

Estou tentando executar essa procedure:

```
DECLARE
x NUMBER;
y NUMBER;
z NUMBER;
BEGIN
exec sTsAPITransfBloqueioJudicial( '12399729000100', 86, 12399729000100, 1,'18-OCT-22' ,1, 100002315, 'STR', 547.17, 237, 570, 570, 012345678912345678, 'S', 'S', :x, :y, :z);
END;
```

Porem estou tendo o erro abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
begin
declare x number;
declare y number;
declare z number;
exec sTsAPITransfBloqueioJudicial( '12399729000100', 86, 12399729000100, 1,'18-OCT-22' ,1, 100002315, 'STR', 547.17, 237, 570, 570, 012345678912345678, 'S', 'S', :x, :y, :z);
end
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 3, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the following:

begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>
<a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete
exists prior
06550. 00000 - "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
Cause: Usually a PL/SQL compilation error. Action:
```

Comment: Qual rodou ? O Declare é só uma vez. X,y e z seriam parâmetros informados ? Sendo um bloco eu faria a variável receber o valor na declaração e passaria ela na chamada da procedure (já que teria de digitar mesmo) , mas explique melhor o problema.

Answer (score -1):

Como eu faria posto que vai executar em um bloco plsql, altere os valores de x,y e z por execução , poderiam ser um parâmetros  mas teria de digitar de qualquer forma.

Nota : SEMPRE informe o formato da data , evita dor de cabeça em vários casos, pesquise depois se quiser mais detalhes.

```
DECLARE
  /*torne explicito que é variável pelo nome*/
  VN_X NUMBER := 1;--valores "chutados"
  VN_Y NUMBER := 2;
  VN_Z NUMBER := 3;
BEGIN
  sTsAPITransfBloqueioJudicial('12399729000100', 
                               86, 
                               12399729000100, 
                               1,
                               to_date('18-10-22','DD-MM-YY),/*explicita formato data*/
                               1, 
                               100002315, 
                               'STR', 
                               547.17, 
                               237, 
                               570, 
                               570, 
                               012345678912345678, 
                               'S', 
                               'S', 
                               VN_X, 
                               VN_Y, 
                               VN_Z);
END;
```

[Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/B14251_01/adfns_packages.htm)